# Segmentation fault when calling a class constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to instantiate a class for a specific implementation of a symbol table and, following the instructions for the project, I'm doing it via a pointer. My constructor does a lot as it is the thing building the symbol table from a text file, but I'm getting a Segmentation fault error at the end of the constructor. What I don't understand is what exactly is giving me this error. I've done a bit of debugging and it seems my constructor is running just fine, as it gets to the breakpoint I put at the very last bracket and all the data is in the vector as I expected. When it tries to step out of the constructor and back to the main file, though, it gives me that error.

The main file is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

#include "tabeladesimbolos.hpp"
typedef char * String;
typedef int * Integer;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fstream arqTexto;

    /* abra arquivo com texto */
    arqTexto.open(argv[1]);

    if (arqTexto.fail())
    {
        cout << "ERRO: arquivo" << argv[1] << "nao pode ser aberto.\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    arqTexto.close();

    string nome_arquivo = argv[1];

    /* crie a ST*/
    cout << "criando ST...\n";

    /* usadas para medir tempo de processamento */
    clock_t start, end;
    double elapsed = 0;

    start = clock();
    vetorDes *st = new vetorDes(nome_arquivo);
    end = clock();

    /* calcule o tempo */
    elapsed = ((double)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << "arquivo lido e ST construida em " << elapsed << " segundos\n";

    delete st;

    return 0;
}
```

The error happens in the following line:

```
vetorDes *st = new vetorDes(nome_arquivo);
```

The file with the constructor (tabeladesimbolos.hpp) is:

```
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

typedef char * String;
typedef int * Integer;
using namespace std;

struct Valor
{
    String chave;
    Integer valor;
};

class vetorDes
{
    vector<Valor> vetor;

public:
    vetorDes(string nomeArquivo);
    void insere(String chave, Integer valor);
    Integer devolve(String chave);
};

vetorDes::vetorDes(string nomeArquivo)
{
    ifstream arqTexto;
    String palavra;
    Integer aux = nullptr;
    vetor.reserve(10000);
    arqTexto.open(nomeArquivo);
    while (arqTexto >> palavra)
    {
        aux = devolve(palavra);
        if (aux == nullptr)
        {
            int* um = new int;
            *um = 1;
            insere(palavra, um);
        }
        else
        {
            (*aux)++;
        }
    }
}

void vetorDes::insere(String chave, Integer valor)
{
    Valor *aux = new Valor;
    aux->chave = (String) malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(aux->chave, chave);
    aux->valor = valor;
    int maxsize = vetor.max_size();
    int currentsize = vetor.size();
    vetor.push_back(*aux);
    return;
}

Integer vetorDes::devolve(String chave)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < vetor.size(); ++i)
    {
        String teste = vetor[i].chave;
        if (!strcasecmp(teste, chave))
        {
            return vetor[i].valor;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

My debugger gets me to that last } in the constructor without error, which leads me to believe the problem is with the way I allocate something as it only comes up when the program tries to finish the "new vetorDes" call.

The full error message is:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI___libc_free (mem=0x3b002e6f746e6174) at malloc.c:3103
```

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: `arqTexto >> palavra` tries to write through an uninitialized pointer

Comment: Things will go much easier if you stop using raw pointers, and use `std::string` and `int` instead of String and Integer

Answer (score 0):

> `__GI___libc_free (mem=0x3b002e6f746e6174)`

The `0x3b002e6f746e6174` is obviously invalid pointer:

- it's not in [canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Virtual_address_space_details),
- its tail looks like `ASCII` string `tanto.`

It is safe to assume that you have some kind of heap overflow (or other heap corruption). Use [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org) or [Address Sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) to find the bug.

As N.M. noted, you are doing yourself a great disservice by hiding pointers behind these typedefs:

```
typedef char * String;
typedef int * Integer;
```

The bug would be much more noticeable if you didn't:

```
char *palavra;  // uninitialized pointer
...
while (arqTexto >> palavra) // BUG: writes to random memory
```

Comment: Thank you! I've looked into it and "tanto." is the last word of the document I was using as source, which shows you were correct that it was that pointer causing all the problems. Properly allocating it and freeing it at the end solved the problem.

About using the typedefs, I'm not a fan either, I'm using them like that as it's the interface that was required. But I'll definitely be on the lookout for other instances of this kind of thing so I don't have anymore problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
String palavra; 
...
while (arqTexto >> palavra)
```

I didn't see anything between declaring palavra, which is a pointer, and reading into it, that made palavara point anywhere.  The pointer is uninitialized, so it points to some random place, and you are reading your data into that random place.  Anything can happen then, except anything good.